# Access MySql Databases from same Network or Remotely access from Different Servers

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application in which I have to access all pc connected to same network and their MySql Databases and I also want want to connect to remotely a server.

Actually I have list of drop down services and each service holding a database name. when I select a service then I want to build connection to database either it lies on same network or any remote server.

Remember, I know the hostname, username, password and dbname. and I am using mysqli_connect function.

I have try multiple options given on web, but all in vain. e.g grant host and user access. But not found any solution can help to solve my problem.

I have try bind-address option in my.conf file but no solution.

Here is my code

For remote Server
$con = new mysqli_connect('xxx xxx xxx:3306', 'username', 'pass', 'dbname');

For local Network
$con =  new mysqli_connect('xxxx xxx xxx:3306', 'localhost', '', 'talent');

> Error

mysqli::mysqli();(HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected  host has failed to respond.  and also get this one earlier Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

I am using windows platform. WIndow 8.1

Comment: What error do you get?  Also, `new mysqli_connect` looks very suspicous to me.  See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: mysqli::mysqli();(HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected  host has failed to respond.  and also get this one earlier Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to access mysql database installed on different computers on same network as your computer and also on some remote server.

What you need is IP Addresses of all the computers on which the mysql server is installed including the remote server. And on each such computer mysql server remote access should be enabled for your computer's IP Address and mysql user you are using in 'new mysqli_connect()'. See [this](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/remotemysql.htm) tutorial.

Also as fvu said check php documentation for 'mysqli_connect' function.

**UPDATED**


**What is SSH?**

1. SSH is SecureSHell.

2. Its nothing but a remote login tool or program(like telnet but in secured way).

3. Remote login is logging in to some other computer(known as remote computer) as a user of that computer from your computer.

4. After you successfully logged in to the remote computer via ssh, you can type commands on that remote computer on behalf of the user you are loggen in with.

5. Consider this as if you are sitting in front of your computer and watching the command prompt(terminal in linux and mac) screen of the remote computer.

6. Whataver you will type here will reflect there.


**For your knowledge to make you understand the problem:**

1. When you install XAMPP or WAMP on your computer it also installs MySQL Server with it.

2. MySQL Server is a process running in the background to which we can request to do 
database operations like SELECT, UPDATE, etc.

3. This thing we generally do using 'mysql_connect' or 'mysqli_connect' in php.

4. MySQL Server can have many users and different users have different previledges/permissions. So that MySQL admin user(i.e. root) can control what things are allowed and not allowed for a user.

5. Now while connecting to the mysql server process we need to specify the user credentials. That you specify in mysqli_connect function.


**Now let me explain you why you are getting that error:**

1. The user credentials you are using either does not exist or not correct or the user has no access to connect to MySQL Server process remotely. i.e. from other computer that the one has MySQL Server installed on. In your case from your computer to computer A or to computer B or remote server.

2. The other reason may be the firewall settings of remote computers.


**Solution:**

1. For computer A and computer B you don't need ssh you can directly go to the computer and open command prompt on it and type commands.

2. But for remote computer you need to use ssh.

3. Now another problem is you are using Windows so ssh program will not be available to you.

4. You will need to download putty program. Its ssh implementation for windows. Same as ssh only name is different.

5. Take a putty tutorial to connect to remote server.

6. Then you can use  [this](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/remotemysql.htm)  tutorial for granting remote login access to mysql user you are using in mysqli_connect function.

Comment: Yes, That thing I want you mentioned "access mysql database installed on different computers on same network as your computer ". I Have read the article but I have no idea what is ssh and how to login. Suppose Three pcs(A, B, Mine) on same network. I want to access A, B Databases. How can I do ? What's changes I have to perform on A, B Pcs and what changes should be performed on Mine PCs. Later on, I also want to connect to remote server. I am using xampp server and Pcs A and B are using Xampp and Wamp respectively.

Comment: Thanks alot for giving too much details. Please tell me about commands: "For computer A and computer B you don't need ssh you can directly go to the computer and open command prompt on it and type commands." What commands I have to type. I beginner and not too much familiar about it.

Comment: I am using xampp and my friend is using wamp. I want to access all databases on my friend pc. So for I have tried in the following ways. 1. Open phpmyadmin on friend pc and created a new user with password and assign it to a database. I have set privileges for this database any host(%) can access it. Also grant all query on friend pc for all privilege. Remember My friend is using window platform. Then on my own pc in mysqli_connect('friendPC IP','username','password','dbname'); but failed to connect and got error mysqli::mysqli():(HY000/1045)

Comment: Try disabling windows firewall on your friends pc and also disable antivirus firewall if any. And also confirm the username, password and db name of mysqli_connect function matches with one you created from phpmyadmin and try passing one more argument to mysqli_connect function i.e. 3306

Comment: I have tried this , but I have not got any error, but I am waiting for response and no response was generated and after few seconds max execution time over and no erro was found.

Comment: Even though i have develop a new rule to allow connection from port 3306. But unable to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is a local hosted database and you can connect to it from local host and i you are not able to connect to it from a remote machine consider the following options.

1. There is a firewall in ubuntu that you need to open, you do this by granting access in IPtables.

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT And now we should be able to login to our server from our local machine:

mysql -h255.112.324.12 -uroot -pMyPASSWORD

You need

2. to grant access to mysql: https://askubuntu.com/questions/159053/mysql-server-not-accessible-from-remote-machine

as root, open your /etc/mysql/my.cnf with your favorite editor look for the [mysqld] section, and in there for the bind-address keyword. This usually is set to 127.0.0.1 -- change that to match your "normal" IP-address save the file, and reload the service (e.g. using service mysql restart)

3. Last but not least you need to give remote access in mysql:

GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyPASSWORD';

Find more information here: http://web.archive.org/web/20120930214828/http://chosencollective.com/technology/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Right now you seem to be mixing object-oriented and procedural approaches.  If you want to use object-orented approach, `mysqli` object should be instantiated as follows:

```
$con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname, $socket); // all but first parameter are optional
```

If you want to use procedural approach, mysqli connection resource should be created as follows:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname, $socket); // all but first parameter are optional
```

Comment: I am using object oriented approach